# Why is Poland's proposed Holocaust speech law so controversial?

Tags: law, freedom-of-speech, poland

From what I understood, the law focuses on 2 things:

1. Calling death camps located in Nazi-occupied Poland "Polish death camps".
2. Blaming Poland as a nation for the Holocaust.

It seems only the second point is controversial, especially in Israel. As far as I understand the main criticism is, that it would prohibit discussing incidents, where Polish individuals collaborated with the Nazis.

Isn’t there already consensus, that Poland, as a nation and state, is not to blame for the Holocaust?

Isn't the law specifically formulated in a way, which would still allow individuals to be blamed for collaboration?

So what is everyone arguing about?

Comment: Is the law specifically targeting the *English* phrase "Polish death camps"? Because while in English, this could mean either "death camps in Poland" (location) or "death camps run by Polish people" (blame), this sort of ambiguous construct does not exist in the Polish language and there are different adjectival forms to mean either. Then again, I only have an elementary education in the Polish language, so I cannot comment on this further.

Comment: I think this question could do a better job presenting the content of the law in question or link to a relevant resource. See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amendment_to_the_Act_on_the_Institute_of_National_Remembrance

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the ambiguity is the same in Polish ("polskie obozy śmierci" can mean both "operated by Poland" and "located in Poland").

Comment: Please stop re-adding the Israel tag. This question does not even mention Israel.

Comment: @Philipp What is wrong with adding the Israel tag? Poland was historically the country with the most Jewish people living there, until the Holocaust. It's hard to understand the history of Poland and the history of Israel without understanding both, no?

Comment: @user1721135 I think the answer to this question may have something to do with how history is taught and learned. I posted another question in the history section that may be relevant:  https://history.stackexchange.com/q/43486/27930

Comment: @jwco (RE: tagging) If that were the policy, questions would each need a number far greater than 5 tags. The question does not pertain to Israel, so it should not have the tag. It is as simple as that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73062/discussion-on-question-by-user1721135-why-is-polands-proposed-holocaust-speech).

Comment: I don't think that the Israel tag is that big of a problem for this question.  [The Wikipedia article on this issue has a subsection for "Israeli reactions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Polish_death_camp%22_controversy#Israeli_reactions), so In my opinion, It's reasonable to assume that an expert on Israeli politics would be well suited to answering this question.

Comment: Here's a detailed analysis regarding the the act in dispute: http://en.ordoiuris.pl/institute-activity/report-article-55a-act-amending-act-institute-national-remembrance

Comment: This question is [being discussed](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3298/101) on Meta.

Answer (score 62):

**The Law and Polish Complicity in the Holocaust**

While "Poland as a nation" is not to blame for the Holocaust, and while there was no official cooperation between Poland and Germany, government institutions as well as individual Poles [collaborated with the Nazis](https://www.ushmm.org/information/press/press-releases/collaboration-and-complicity-during-the-holocaust) (see also [here](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2018/02/poland-holocaust-death-camps/552455/)):

> As German forces implemented the killing, they drew upon some Polish agencies, such as Polish police forces and railroad personnel, in the guarding of ghettos and the deportation of Jews to the killing centers. Individual Poles often helped in the identification, denunciation, and hunting down of Jews in hiding, often profiting from the associated blackmail, and actively participated in the plunder of Jewish property.

Poland has a long and strong history of antisemitism. Before WWII, the "Jewish Question" was an important political topic and there were [calls](https://books.google.de/books?id=t6h2pI7o_zQC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=poland+jews+removal&source=bl&ots=xmdIkrFVSK&sig=zEbfiibPMXNBDRj097Kot-PGI3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSgPeTwZ3ZAhXOMywKHYgYDVY4ChDoAQgoMAA#v=onepage&q=poland%20jews%20removal&f=false) to deport all Jews. Currently, Poland has among the highest rates of antisemites in Europe (about a third of the population according to [PEW](http://www.pewglobal.org/2015/06/02/faith-in-european-project-reviving/), and an index of 45% according to the [ADL](http://global100.adl.org/#map/eeurope)). And before, during, and after WWII, Poles carried out pogroms against Jews.

Those that oppose the new law fear that it will suppress legitimate criticism of Polish actions and antisemitism during the war. They see it as an attempt to [whitewash history](https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/poland-s-holocaust-law-is-a-licence-to-whitewash-history-1.3383516).

It is difficult to say whether or not the law will be applied that way (my guess is that it probably will not), but the relevant part is that it leaves the impression of rejecting legitimate criticism about Polish involvement in the Holocaust. As the World Holocaust Remembrance Center [said](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/02/01/europe/poland-passes-holocaust-bill-intl/index.html):

> restrictions on statements by scholars and others regarding the Polish people's direct or indirect complicity with the crimes committed on their land during the Holocaust are a serious distortion.

**Context and rising Polish Nationalism**

A lot of the worry is not about the exact content of the law itself though, but the context around it, specifically increasing nationalism stoked by the right wing Law and Justice party. As the [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/feb/01/poland-holocaust-speech-law-senate-israel-us) says:

> Many observers believe the party has reignited the debate on the Holocaust as a deliberate ploy to further fuel nationalist sentiment among its voters.

[The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2018/02/poland-holocaust-law/552842/) shares this view:

> But this law isn’t about the finer points of history. It is aimed at shoring up the right-wing base of the governing Law and Justice party

**Free Speech**

Another criticism, mainly from the US, is that the law restricts free speech (see eg CNN link above).

Comment: Timothy Snyder at Yale has a more nuanced history in his book, Blood Lands

Comment: @CJDennis your comment "It implies that Jews are not Poles" lacks context. You (so it seems) think it's about "nationality" i.e. citizenship; the respondendts most surely saw it in terms of ethnicity. Ethnically, Jews are most certainly not Poles, as they also are not Russians, Ukrainians, or Germans (can't use "American" here as that is not an ethnicity, which probably contributes to the typically American confusion on these issues). Jews are Jews. It is not just religion; Jews call themselves "the People of Israel" for three millennia at least.

Comment: @tim Thanks for the references about "calls to deport" Jews in the 1930s. I did not know about them. But I also have to wonder if any such calls were made with the intention, even if not stated, to save lives, and to prevent the invasion and occupation of Poland that followed. Would you like to comment on why you think the Jewish population in Poland decreased in percent between 1900 and 1939? As well, why do you think it ranked 1st until the Holocaust? Maybe you could mention Poland's history of legislation such as the Statute of Kalisz and the Warsaw Confederation too.

Comment: @tim What do you mean when you use the adjective "strong" regarding the phrase "history of antisemitism"?

Comment: @jwco Many Poles protested the filming of part of the file Schindler's List on location in Poland, screaming "Jews Go Home" at the production staff.  

At the time, the official Jewish population of Poland was about two dozen individuals.  And, of course, hardly all of the production staff were Jews.

Seems like "strong antisemitism" to me.

Modern Polish antisemitism may go back to the 1600s-1800s when absentee landowners who would often appoint a Jew as his representative, (Jews were often the only literate ones).  The Jews would collect his rent, which would make them very unpopular.

Comment: @Jeffiekins Thank you for your comment. I still don't understand what you mean by the phrase "strong antisemitism". Would you provide a source for the Schindler's list story and the landlord history?

Comment: "It is difficult to say whether or not the law will be applied that way (my guess is that it probably will not)" Even if the law isn't enforced much, the threat of enforcement could still stifle historical discussion.

Comment: @Colin the authorities have already put out a call for anyone feeling slighted to lodge a complaint about it. i.e. this is a call to report on anyone in breach of the new law, as any regular citizen would see it.

Comment: I wonder, Is that mythical "long and strong antisemitism" the reason that statistically most "Righteous Among the Nations" are Poles? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Righteous_Among_the_Nations Or maybe are you referring to people who risked their lives during WW2 to protect Jews? Because you surely don't refer to minor nationalist groups, which are present in almost all countries and *don't* represent the opinion of majority (though obviously scream most loudly)?

Comment: Did your sources mean this police: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Police? Some quotes for you "In October 1939, General Governor Hans Frank ordered the mobilization of the pre-war Polish police into the service of the Germans. The policemen were to report for duty or face the death penalty." "...all of its high-ranking officers came from the ranks of the German police (Kriminalpolizei)." Or entire, actually sourced chapter which directly contradicts claims about massive compliance? Generalising like done by you and sources you quote is exactly the reason this law was introduced.

Comment: By the way, this document: http://en.ordoiuris.pl/institute-activity/report-article-55a-act-amending-act-institute-national-remembrance contains information about history of Poles and Jews ranging to 1264, I wonder is this what you mean by "long and strong antisemitism"...

Comment: @Jeffiekins, so I understand, that you judge relations between two nationalities by a single incident? How many Poles (in percentage) took place in that incident? How many of them were members of *minor* national groups in Poland, who *do not* represent opinion of majority? How does it relate to Poles risking their lives helping Jews *survive* through WW2?

Comment: A general response: I am not going to engage those trying to minimize or whitewash antisemitism in Poland, and this is not the place to discuss good deeds done by individual Poles or the Polish nation. For those with genuine questions about the history of antisemitism in Poland, I suggest to open a question specifically about that here or at history.SE.

Comment: Anyone interested in Polish "long and strong" antisemitism may visit: http://www.anti-defamation.pl/rdiplad/z-potrzeby-serca/ (scroll down for English version). These are real stories told by still living witnesses or their families.

Comment: @tim So... fighting slander/libel is now whitewashing, and it's not a place to discuss good things but it's a great place to discuss bad things? For example your initial claim about government institutions is an outright lie.

Comment: @Miech I don't see slander or libel. Yes, the law is specifically about bad things, so bad things are the topic here; good things are generally also important, but aren't the topic here. I provided a reputable source for all my claims. If you doubt them, maybe ask about it at history.SE or skeptics.SE.

Comment: While it is very convenient to think that the Holocaust was conducted by some alien Nazi, the truth, not so obvious these days is that Germans did that. Not Nazis. Germans. German State and German Nation.

Regarding antisemitism in Poland before WW2, Jews chose Poland because no other country was safer for them in Europe. Polish antisemites broke them a window and said something unpleasant. German antisemites burned Jews alive. Which one is worse?

And even today, it is in Germany where synagogues require Police to secure them. Not in Poland.

Comment: Let me comment on the prase "Poland has a long and strong history of antisemitism."

1. all the Europe has it. 
2. in Poland it was more visible because it had the largest Jewish minority of all countries in Europe.

Comment: @Jeffiekins
"Poles protested the filming of part of the file Schindler's List on location in Poland, screaming "Jews Go Home" at the production staff. At the time, the official Jewish population of Poland was about two dozen individuals". IMDB says the movie was shot between 1 March 1993 - 11 May 1993, according to YIVO at the time, the population of Jews in Poland was around ~3700 (so more than now). Other sources give numbers up to 30 times bigger (100k). What else is manipulated and inaccurate in your replies?

Comment: _As German forces implemented the killing, they drew upon some Polish agencies, such as Polish police forces_ - it is worth pointing out that large fraction of the blue police where active involved in the resistance, and number of officers have been awarded the Righteous Among the Nations, and significant numbers for resistance and lack of collaboration. At the same Nazis actively used ethnic Jews to [police getthos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Ghetto_Police). You can be sure there is nothing black and white in the history of WWII Poland.

Comment: @user19142 while I understand what you're saying, I think at least the actions by SS were pretty monochrome black, in WWII Poland. So "nothing" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @user1880 I hindsight "nothing" wasn't the most fortunate choice of word. The point I was trying to made, is that the scale of atrocities exposed a whole scale of human behaviors, from the worst imaginable atrocities to incredible acts of kindness and bravery. And while many individual acts lie on one, or another end of the spectrum, making shallow generalized judgments, given the scale of the scale of the tragedy, is just unacceptable.

Comment: @user19142 as I said, I understand what you're saying. glad we see it eye to eye. one point about your answer while I have your ear, Ukrainian Insurgent Army was hardly "Soviets". I think you'll agree on this one too.

Comment: @GenlyAi If you think that the particular sentence is somehow ambiguous feel free to make an edit. Suggesting any connection between UPA and the Soviet Union was of course not the intention - the point was to provide a broader context, without going off-topic. Hence a single sentence.

Comment: @tim _I provided a reputable source for all my claims. If you doubt them, maybe ask about it at history.SE or skeptics.SE_ - so [I did](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/40693/43898).  Intrestignely enough ooks like your comments with attempts to diminish scale of genocide on Polish population and whitewash Judenrats and  Jewish Ordnungspolizei  made [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/40716/43898) were removed and sadly not captured by [wayback](https://goo.gl/1u5Dzn) machine, but please don't sell your political agenda as a historical truth.

Answer (score 17):

The issue is not so much about "Polish death camps" but about doubts of how far does the law go, or how far will future laws go.

While the death camps, during WWII there where a few cases were Polish people did commit war crimes; either as individuals colaborating with the Germans, [in operations together with the German occupation forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedwabne_pogrom) or even [by units of the underground resistence army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paw%C5%82okoma_massacre)(AK).

Studies around these events have always been a sensitive issue, for political reasons. During the Soviet period they would have been used to attack AK and the German occupation; after the Soviet period [commanders of the AK involved in massacres were rehabilitated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubingiai_massacre); assigning blame for the massacres led to tension between Poland and several ex-SU republics, etc.

If laws are implemented as stated by the OP, there is little reason to worry. But there are some issues raised:

- What do exactly the laws say? It probably is not very difficult to word such a law to add protection against people remembering those actions<sup>1</sup>. And even if in its current form this does not happen, it sets a precedent to allow for future changes of the law to that effect.
- Why? It is not as if there is a lot of confusion about who established and managed the death camps<sup>2</sup>. If the objectives are those stated by the OP, there seems to be no need to criminalize such narrative, as it is not seriously considered anywhere, in the same way that there is no law forbidding people from claiming that the Earth is flat.
- Add to all of the above that the current government of Poland is very nationalist, not very good at tolerating criticism and that [there have been previous attempts by officials of this government to shift the blame of those  massacres and deny Polish implication](https://www.haaretz.com/world-news/europe/polish-ministers-deny-poles-involvement-in-massacres-of-jews-1.5411291)

So, on these basis, is not that difficult to understand how many people may be worried about the the intent of this law going well beyond what the OP understands, and towards forbidding any mention or study of less-than-honorable actions by some Polish people during these years, in a case of historic revisionism.

**UPDATE:** Trilarion's comment to the OP [linked to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amendment_to_the_Act_on_the_Institute_of_National_Remembrance), which includes part of the translated text of the law:

> 1. [Anyone] who, in public and against the facts, ascribes to the Polish People or to the Polish State, responsibility or co-responsibility for Nazi crimes committed by the Third Reich, [as] defined in Article 6 of the Charter of the International Military Tribunal, Annex to the Agreement for the prosecution and punishment of the major war criminals of the European Axis, signed in London on August 8, 1945 [...], or for other offences which are crimes against peace [or] humanity or [that are] war crimes, or who otherwise grossly reduces the responsibility of the actual perpetrators of said crimes, is subject to a fine or [to] imprisonment for up to 3 years. The judgment shall be made public.

An strict reading of this text would make illegal any references to the Polish collaborators with Nazi Germany and/or Polish participants in the [Jedwabne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedwabne_pogrom), [Kielce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kielce_pogrom) and other massacres, thus giving support to the critics' concerns<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>So far I have only found references to declarations by member of the government, but no independent description of the actual scope of the law.

<sup>2</sup>In all of the references to "Polish death camps" that I have been able to find, it was very clear that the issuer was meaning a *geographic* reference and that it was not a way of blaming Poland for them.

<sup>3</sup>I find particularly telling the differentiation between "Polish" and "Ukrainian" responsabilities. It shows that the intent of the law is not to avoid excuses for German responsability but as a law with the intent of forbidding criticism of Polish actions; perhaps looking to establish a narrative of a flawless Poland inhabited by flawless heroes who were victimized by all of their neighbours.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73131/discussion-on-answer-by-sjuan76-why-is-polands-proposed-holocaust-speech-law-so).

Comment: _An strict reading of this text would make illegal any references to the Polish collaborators..._ - this is not true. The same act (in fact the same article) clearly persecutes denial of crimes investigated by the Institute of National Remembrance, including crimes committed by the Polish nationals. Also Kielce Pogrom is hardly relevant in the context of amendment, as it is not attributed as a Nazi crime.

Comment: *In all of the references to "Polish death camps" that I have been able to find, it was very clear that the issuer was meaning a geographic reference and that it was not a way of blaming Poland for them.* - how come then other camps are referred to as Nazi concentration camp - like, for example Vught KZ, and not instead of **DUTCH CONCENTRATION CAMP**? And why - as I documented in my answer below - said sentence is used to support the case that they were run or aided in running by Poles?

Answer (score 14):

There is a growing tendency to paint WWII as an alien invasion where a few dozen people were responsible for creating a war and death machinery and operating it with everybody else being a victim and/or resistance fighter.

The truth is that occupation forces were vastly outnumbered by local administration helping with the occupation everywhere and people arranging themselves with circumstances.  Without Hitler going to all-out war against everybody and thus forcing the hands of the allies, the outcome would have been very different.  And even then, a number of countries just rolled over when the occupation forces came, and the main road block in the end was that the Russian bear was far too large to roll over and the Germans were spread too thin to have any effect or control, even though they exacted a harsh price where they were.  In short: WWII did not end like it did because Hitler was a madman (there was no shortage of those) but because he was a megalomaniac idiot.

The world is a better place for that outcome but paid a terrible price that we don't lightly want to be paying again.

Being in denial about one's own country's contributions may be nice for everybody's historical ego (not least of all the Germans themselves) but it does little for avoiding a recurrence, and indeed the nationalism forming the root of both World Wars is strongly on the incline.  The refusal to accept responsibility for the awful consequences of induced mass behavior in the past is a direct precursor for refusing to admit awful consequences of induced mass behavior in the future.

Humans have a tribal nature: "us versus them" is always going to appeal to the primal urges of the underlying animal we have built civilizations with.  Prohibiting to paint an ugly picture where an ugly picture is called for is sacrificing the tools for fighting a larger evil for the sake of some ease of mind.

Comment: The question is "Why is the new Polish law controversial?" not "What was the role of the Polish state and people in the death camps?"

Comment: Sorry, this answer while insightful does not address the question asked.

Comment: a country didn't even had 2b occupied or allied with Germany to contribute to the Holocaust. Britain for example forbade Jewish refugees entry to Mandatory Palestine, refused port entry to refugee ships like Struma, which ended in all its passangers drowning, but one. The US put their weight to forbidding Jewish refugees entry even to the nominally independent Cuba as was the case with one famous ship; the much reduced quotas for the Jewish immigration into the US went half unused during the war. Finns OTOH did not give up their Jews to the Nazis (but they did the non-Finnish Jewish refugees).

Comment: @grovkin The answer does nothing to link the stated history to the law. "Controversial" means that people argue about it; if everybody's deluding themselves that nothing happened, there's nothing to argue about.

Answer (score 7):

The law is too broad. Any mention of the Polish nation having contributed to the Holocaust could get you in trouble. Yes, you can talk about the individual acts. But you can't tie them into a bigger picture. Obviously, a law making what many consider the truth illegal is going to be controversial.

If the law only talked about the Polish state (as opposed to both the nation and state) it would perhaps be less controversial.

Comment: I guess it depends heavily on what really happened. If it is clear cut, that the Polish nation didn't contribute to the holocaust as a nation, then this probably would be less controversial. While the holocaust denial laws are also controversial, because they limit speech, people accept them, because the holocaust clearly happened.

Comment: Downvoted as the law specifically says "against the facts" - so it is not making the truth illegal, it is making false accusations illegal.

Comment: @NickC it's a very vague expression. Unless the law defined what it considers "facts" or "nation" the chilling effect is inevitable. But you're right that illegal is the wrong word.

Comment: I think the "against the facts" shouldn't be dismissed so easily. This makes it kind of similar to the holocaust denial crimes.

Comment: @kotelcat - maybe but the answer does not explain that.  Improve your answer to explain that and I suspect you will have some downvotes reversed.  I would probably get away from the speculation about what would make it better.  That is not asked for and your speculation is for lack of a better term, contested.

Comment: @NickC Actually, I read "and against the facts" not as meaning that truth is a defense (note that "truth" is notably absent from the list of exceptions in the 3rd point of the law), but as meaning "as starting point, the truth is that Poland and the Polish People had no responsability at all". It stablishes *by law* what the historical truth is...

Comment: @SJuan76 The same legal act prosecutes Holocaust denial, similarly establishing certain legal boundaries. It also specifically excludes _scholarly activity_ (Article 55a(3)).

Comment: The political and societal context is very important here. People who endorse the law, including the President of Poland have made it very clear they won't accept the Polish nation having any responsibility for the holocaust. They make it clear it's not okay to relate acts of some Poles to the nation at large. And this thinking isn't exactly controversial in Poland. Just to illustrate - most of the opposition politicians are rabidly against the ruling party. But this time almost all of them only abstained. Most domestic criticism is about foreign policy implications.

Comment: @kotelcat Why would it be controversial? Unless you know the evidence supporting state or nationwide participation (and ~70 years after the events, we can safely assume that such evidence would already emerged, it was indeed the case) any other position would be surprising. If suggest that such evidence exist, I would appreciate a response [to my question on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/40693/43898).

Comment: @user19142 this is where the vagueness of the term "nation" comes in. It's widely known antisemitism was very common all across Europe. Poland was no exception. Segregation, exclusion from many areas of life, anti-Jewish protests and riots, you name it. Many view the prevalent European jew hatred as a key ingredient that laid foundations for the Holocaust. And the "individual acts" of violent Polish antisemitism can also be viewed as having been enabled by the society at large. Whether one views that as national "responsibility" is pretty subjective. The Polish authorities certainly do not.

Comment: @kotelcat It was widespread across both Europe and US. But please note that, the act itself, is not in anyway limited to Nazi crimes committed against Jewish population, but covers crimes against  _persons of Polish nationality or Polish citizens of other nationalities_ and as such applies to extermination of other groups, including but not limited to, ethnic Poles, Roma people and Belarusians. It also covers crimes not motivated ethnically. I included relevant parts of the law in my answer for the reference, but "Holocaust law" is not a precise description of the act.

Comment: And the purpose of the law is to prevent statements like yours to be made without any basis. What you did was textbook case of assigning blame based on the hearsay, not the fact. The bigger picture was this: Poland was the ONLY country that used it's resources during the war to help persecuted Jews in Poland. Poland was the ONLY country to regularly request help from Allied Powers in that effort. Poland was the ONLY country where penalty for harboring Jews was death of the whole family where Jews were found - and neighbors - by execution on the spot... So... what is your *"bigger picture"*?

Comment: @AcePL as I mentioned in the comments, the bigger picture, is that of universal European Jew-hatred which ultimately enabled the Holocaust. And the Polish nation would certainly be no exception.

Comment: @kotelcat - which doesn't address the issue. The problem is that Poland is uniquely targeted as exceptionally anti-semitic, with basically excusing everyone else. For example mentioned by me Rabbi Zev Friedman compares Poland to Denmark (where almost all Jews were rescued), but forgets to mention there was less than 8000 of them there in total. He doesn't mention Netherlands, he doesn't know there was a death camp there, doesn't mention French and their Jews' deportations... This is the bigger picture, and Poland is still an exception. That's why I'm asking about ***your** bigger picture*...

Comment: @AcePL that does nothing to justify the law. Some people being unfair to Poland is irrelevant. Two wrongs don't make a right.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the law in question is particularly controversial for three reasons:

- It is implemented mostly to express specific ideological stance, not out of actual necessity, as of majority of possible cases, would be out of Polish jurisdiction (and are more likely to result in diplomatic incidents) and more often a result of limited historical knowledge, than anything else.

  In this context some international comments are perceived as an attack on Polish sovereignty.

  As such it is viewed as an extension of an politicized view of the history and it is troubling, despite of limited practical applications, at least in terms of criminal law (civil lawsuits which might be enabled by this law, are different topic).
- It touches deeply complex and painful historical events, and any discussion around it, naturally becomes highly emotional and quickly escalates.

  For the nation, who lost over 5 million citizens (2.7 million ethnic Poles, 2.7- 2.9 ethnic Jews or Jewish descent, as well as Polish nationals belonging to other ethnic groups) in both death camps, as well as number of actions against civilian population (like [Außerordentliche Befriedungsaktion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_AB-Aktion_in_Poland)), during [Warsaw Ghetto Uprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Ghetto_Uprising) (with 13.000 killed during Uprising alone), 56,885 deported, mostly civilians (German estimate), as an outcome of [Warsaw Uprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Uprising) (with 50.000–70.000 civilians killed during [Wola massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wola_Massacre) and [Ochota massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ochota_massacre)) to Nazis alone (with many thousands more killed by Soviets - [Katyn massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyn_massacre) and  Ukrainian Insurgent Army - [Massacres of Poles in Volhynia and Eastern Galicia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacres_of_Poles_in_Volhynia_and_Eastern_Galicia)) any accusations of being a Nazi accomplice are not taken lightly. Especially if you consider that many responsible for the atrocities, were never brought to justice.

  To quote [the article](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/02/01/europe/poland-passes-holocaust-bill-intl/index.html) already linked by [tim](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/8062/tim)

  > Successive governments have been trying to persuade journalists and politicians to stop using the phrase 'Polish death camps,'" she told CNN.
  >
  > "It comes down to a rather sloppy and cavalier attitude towards Polish history... towards one of the most painful periods in Polish history."

  Events like President Barack Obama referring to "Polish death camp" or  James Comey speaking "the murderers and accomplices of Germany, and Poland" caused outrage in Poland and are only the most prominent examples.

  To give you some perspective, from Polish point of view suggesting that Poland or Polish citizens are in general responsible for Nazi atrocities is pretty much as unacceptable as [claims that the Jewish councils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judenrat#The_role_of_the_Judenr%C3%A4te_in_the_Holocaust) where somehow a willing accomplice of the Holocaust. I will risk to say, that calling the law, "Holocaust speech law", already shows, how little is known, about the scale of Nazi atrocities in the occupied Poland - which is tragedy which affected more than a single ethnic group, or even a single nation.

  At the same time interwar (newly interdependent) and WWII Polish history is full of ethnical tensions, both internal and external, many of which still reflect on its relationship with its neighbors (mostly Lithuania and Ukraine). In this light, governing historical research with and building ideological historical narrative is at least troubling.
- Significant difference in the approach to freedom of speech, especially when related to nazism (and communism). In particular the article 13th of [THE CONSTITUTION OF THE REPUBLIC OF POLAND](http://www.sejm.gov.pl/prawo/konst/angielski/kon1.htm)

  > Political parties and other organizations whose programmes are based upon totalitarian methods and the modes of activity of nazism, fascism and communism, as well as those whose programmes or activities sanction racial or national hatred, the application of violence for the purpose of obtaining power or to influence the State policy, or provide for the secrecy of their own structure or membership, shall be prohibited.

---

**Note**:

It is also worth pointing out that [the same act](https://ipn.gov.pl/en/about-the-ipn/documents/327,The-Act-on-the-Institute-of-National-Remembrance.html), clearly prosecutes denial of crimes, including crimes committed by Polish individuals and law enforcement (Article 55)

> Anyone who publicly and contrary to the facts denies crimes referred to in Article 1(1) shall be subject to a fine or the penalty of imprisonment of up to 3 years. The sentence shall be made public.

where the Article 1(1)

> the recording, collecting, storing, processing, securing, making available and publishing of the documents of the state security authorities, produced and accumulated from 22 July 1944 until 31 July 1990, as well as the documents of the security authorities of the Third Reich and the Soviet Union relating to:
>
> a)
>
> - the Nazi crimes,
> - the communist crimes
> - other crimes against peace, humanity or war crimes, perpetrated on persons of Polish nationality or Polish citizens of other nationalities between 08 November 1917 until 31 July 1990
>
> b) other politically motivated reprisals, instigated by the officers of the Polish law enforcement agencies or the judiciary or persons acting on their order which were disclosed in the contents of the rulings made on the strength of the Act, dated 23 February 1991, on considering as invalid the rulings made in the cases of persons oppressed for their activities for the cause of an independent Polish State (Journal of Laws  of 2015 item 1583),
>
> c)  the actions of the state security authorities described in art. 5;

So the discussed amendment to the Act is mostly discussed out of its actual context.

**See also**

- [The Yad Vashem response to the Law Passed in the Polish Senate](https://www.yadvashem.org/press-release/01-february-2018-10-04.html)

Comment: I was confused but now I think I understand your first point here from your comment to me on the [related meta page](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/tag-deleted-against-authors-wishes-question-edited-in-order-to-justify-tag-dele). I agree the law seems unlikely to be applied, and that the majority of cases of speaking "against the facts" against Poland fall out of Polish jurisdiction. But does anyone disagree with the law because it seems unlikely to be applied? (maybe folks in Poland?) Or maybe I am not understanding what you mean by "specific ideological stance."

Comment: @jwco I don't follow the discussion that closely, so I cannot give a definitive answer, but my impression is that the law is widely approved (which says a lot, considering highly polarized political landscape). Furthermore, some highly biased international comments, further boost the approval, and in a sense, legitimize the need of the amendment in consequence forcing government's hand.

Comment: Massacre of Katyn not proven to be done by soviets.